# Rellanar un campo con un UPDATE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g

Tengo una tabla llamada **`Federation`** con los siguientes campos:

```
IDFEDERATION--->Primary key,
FEDERATION,
PRESIDENT,
COUNTRY,
IDCOUNTRY-->Foreign Key de Country
```

Y una tabla **`country`** con los siguientes campos:

```
IDCOUNTRY--->Primary key,
ENGLISHNAME,
SPANISHNAME,
LOCALNAME,
```

Pues bien, lo que quiero es rellenar el campo `IDCOUNTRY` de **`federation`** con los datos de `idcountry` de la tabla de **`country`**,el caso es que me lo piden de la siguiente manera...

> c)    Mostrad la instrucción UPDATE que servirá para poblar el campo idCountry de Federation. Para realizar dicho UPDATE utilizad una consulta que obtenga idCountry de Country, utilizando el campo country de Federation y localName de Country.

Hice esto y probé alguna cosa mas pero no consigo lo que se me pide

```
UPDATE federation
SET federation.idcountry = (
SELECT country.idcountry
FROM country
WHERE federation.country and country.localname);
```

Estoy un poco liado ahora mismo, necesito algo de luz.

Comment: Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de las tablas en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Indica exactamente el resultado quieres obtener para esos datos de ejemplo e incorpora el código de tus intentos. Aquí se explica mucho mejor [ask]. Bienvendo a [so]

Comment: No me queda claro cuál es el país que quieres asignarles, o el criterio para asignar país a estos registros.

Comment: A la tabla federation se le añadio el campo idcountry y la tabla country tiene un campo llamado idcountry,lo que quiero es añadir los valores de la tabla country en la tabla federation...Pero no lo consigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estás lejos de la solución, básicamente te hace falta la condición de igualdad en tu consulta, pero además yo la haría un poco menos verbosa.

```
UPDATE federation
   SET idcountry = (SELECT country.idcountry
                      FROM country
                     WHERE country.localname = federation.country);
```

En lenguaje coloquial, esto se leería algo como: Para cada fila de `federación` actualiza el campo `idCountry` con el `idCountry` de la tabla `country` para el que `country.localname` sea igual a `federation.country`.

Comment: Perfecto!Pues si,estaba muy cerca!Funciona perfectamente!